# plotting two simple linear regression scatterplots and lines on one graph from two data sets in R

Tags: r, plot, dataset, regression

I have tried:

```
plot(CORTMaglog~CORTlogB, data = data0, xlab="logCORTB", ylab="log CORT30- CORTB")
abline(lm(CORTMaglog ~ CORTlogB))
```

and

```
plot(CORTMaglog~CORTlogB, data = data1, xlab="logCORTB", ylab="log CORT30- CORTB")
abline(lm(CORTMaglog ~ CORTlogB))
```

and now have two graphs.

How do I have both plots from two different data sets on one graph with lines and scatterplots?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `points`. Here is a reproducible example:

```
x = 1:100
y1 = x^1.2 + x*rnorm(100,0,1)
y2 = 2*x^1.2 + x*rnorm(100,1,0.5)
plot(x,y1)
plot(x,y2)

data1 = cbind(x,y1)
data2 = cbind(x,y2)

plot(y2 ~ x, data=data2,col='blue')
abline(lm(y2 ~ x),col='blue')

points(y1 ~ x, data=data1,col='red')
abline(lm(y1 ~ x),col='red')
```

[image]

**Edit** To answer the question in the comments. To use the `plot` function the way you want to, you need to extract the predictions from the `predict` function. For example:

```
x = 1:100
y1 = x^1.2 + x*rnorm(100,0,1)
data1 = data.frame(cbind(x,y1))

fit = lm(y1~x, data=data1)
y = predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x))
plot(x,y1)
lines(x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Here's what happened: > data1 <- mydata[Elevated == 1, ]
> data0 <- mydata[Elevated == 0, ]
> x = 1:100
> y1 = lm(CORTMaglog~CORTlogB, data = data1)
> y0 = lm(CORTMaglog~CORTlogB, data = data0)
> plot(x,y1)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Comment: Its because y1 in your case is an lm object. If you want to use plot(x,y1) then you need to do y1 = predict(lm(CORTMaglog~CORTlogB, data = data1), newdata = data.frame(x))

Comment: If this is helpful, feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: That makes sense.  However, I have this error message now: 
Warning message:
'newdata' had 100 rows but variables found have 52 rows 
Thanks for helping me with this!

Comment: Don't plot x, plot your x-variable, which might be CORTlogB. You should check that it's length is 52, same as your y variable

Comment: Sorry I mean predict, not plot

Comment: How do I know its length?  Also, CORTlogB is my x variable, so I don't know what I would put there.  Ideas?

Comment: to find its length, you can do length(data1$CORTlogB)   and to predict it, you can just do something like: fit = lm(CORTMaglog~CORTlogB, data = data1)    and y1 = predict(fit)

Comment: OK!  I figured it out.  I did: >data1 <- mydata[Elevated == 1, ] 
> data0 <- mydata[Elevated == 0, ] > plot(CORTMaglog ~ CORTlogB, data=data1,col='blue')
> points(CORTMaglog~CORTlogB,data=data0,col='red')
> abline(lm(CORTMaglog~CORTlogB, data=data1),col='blue')
> abline(lm(CORTMaglog~CORTlogB, data=data0),col='red')  > It worked!  I didn't need to figure out the length problem.  Thanks for all your patience!

Comment: Excellent. Please accept the answer so others will know it was helpful too. Good luck!

Comment: Oh ok. What about the up arrow?

Comment: Sorry, no arrow either.